# How to integrate FluentValidation into MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, fluentvalidation

I have made a simple model that has FluentValidation in it but it does not seem to work.

- My database is updating with empty name and passing
  `TryUpdateModel()`
- I don't get client-side validation errors when I submit my form

I have tried to add `FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();` in `Application_Start()` but it shows that it cannot find `FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider` even though I added using class. I also tried to add `[Validator(typeof(Category))]` on top of my model class but didn't do anything. [This](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) us the resource I've been looking for information.

**Model**

```
public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    virtual public ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryValidator : AbstractValidator<Category>
{
    public CategoryValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Category name is required.");
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Category c)
{
    var category = _db.Categories.Where(x => x.ID == c.ID).SingleOrDefault();
    if (category == null) return HttpNotFound();

    // Update model and return to category list
    if (TryUpdateModel(category)) // it passes with empty name and saves changes
    {
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("index", "category");
    }

    // Something is wrong, return view back
    return View(c);
}
```

Comment: What is the using statement that didn't work?

Comment: @jrummell `using FluentValidation;`

Comment: Try `using FluentValidation.Mvc;`

Comment: @jrummell `FluentValidation.Mvc;` does not exist :|

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're missing the `FluentValidation.Mvc` reference. Try installing the [FluentValidation.MVC4](http://nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation.MVC4) NuGet package.

Then follow the [MVC instructions](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, this type of details is missing in a lot of tutorials and guides that claim to be easy and comprehensive for everyone.